# Simplify geojson coordinates precision with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq, precision, geojson

I am using `jq` to change some properties and lighten the weight of a `geojson` file. The coordinates have too much decimal numbers, so I would like to simplify them to 6 decimals.

The file is originally like that:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": { },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -69.23583984375,
          45.460130637921004
        ]
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

and I would like that precision:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": { },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -69.235840,
          45.460131
        ]
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a straight forward `sprintf` like function in the math library supported by `jq` that allows you to format floating point number with a specified precision e.g. say `'%2.5f'`. But you can use the string functions to convert the number to float and extract the digits and convert it back

```sh
jq '.features[].geometry.coordinates |= 
       map( tostring | capture("(?<n>-?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]{6})").n | tonumber )'
```

Note that this **does not work** when the floats are expressed in scientific notation e.g. of formats like `1.5e9`

---

The suggestion in the [comments by Lea Gris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66243482/simplify-geojson-coordinates-precision-with-jq#comment117118513_66244746) is even better, that it doesn't involve any string manipulation.

Comment: You can use `round` instead like: `jq '.features[].geometry.coordinates |= map( ( . * 100000 | round ) / 100000)' input.json` with the benefit it will work with scientific exponent ten representation

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot. This works for point geometry. In case of using MultiLineString or Polygon geometries, we can use: .geometry.coordinates[][] |= map ...

Comment: `.geometry.coordinates[][][]` for MultiPolygon

Answer (score 0):

GNU  Awk maybe a possibility:

```
awk '/coordinates/ { lne=NR } (NR==lne+1 || NR==lne+2) && /-?[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]++/ { match($0,/-?[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]++/);printf "%s%.6f%s\n",substr($0,1,RSTART-1),substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1);next }1' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk '/coordinates/ { 
                     lne=NR                                       # Track the line number when we see a "coordinates" tag
                   } (NR==lne+1 || NR==lne+2) && /-?[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]++/ { 
                     match($0,/-?[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]++/);   # When the line is one or two ahead of coordinates, and the line contains a floating point number, extract that floating point number.
                     printf "%s%.6f%s\n",substr($0,1,RSTART-1),substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1);             # Construct the line with the data before the floating point number, the number to 6 decimal places and then the text after the number
                     next                                         # Skip to the next line
                   }1' file                                       # Use 1 to print both modified and unmodified lines.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pump your JSON through a **Perl** script that rewrites anything that looks like floating point numbers as numbers with 6 decimal places like this - but it is a bit kludgy and will edit **all** things in your JSON that look like floating point numbers but only you know if that is an issue.

```
GenerateJSON | perl -pe 's/([+-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+)/sprintf("%.6f",$&)/ge'
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": { },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -69.235840,
          45.460131
        ]
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

It is basically a substitution, but the `/ge` at the end makes Perl `evaluate` the `sprintf` in the replacement string.

Note that **Perl** is a standard part of **macOS** - i.e. automatically included with all versions.